# If statement in a for loop being ignored

Tags: javascript

I have a for loop which has an if statement nested inside of it, but the loop is ignoring the statement and continuing to run. Any ideas why this could be? Many thanks.

JavaScript:

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
var cssVal = '';

function changeColor() { 
    for (i = 0; i < sheet.cssRules.length; i++) {
        cssVal = sheet.cssRules[i];
        console.log(cssVal); // Successfully outputs #box to the console.
            if (cssVal == "#box") { // Does nothing, continues iterating.
                console.log("If has run.");
                cssVal.style.backgroundColor="blue";
                break;
            }
    }
}

changeColor();
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";


#box {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

#car {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Boxes</title>
<link href="Boxes.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="car"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Boxes.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with a strict comparison, like this `===`

Comment: Check for leading or trailing spaces in your string, maybe `console.log("|" + cssVal + "|");`

Comment: Your function should really declare "i" as a local variable.

Comment: I'd attach a debugger and *really* dig into what `cssVal` is.  Is it an object?  Does it have other properties?  If it's a string, what's the length?  What's at each character?  Debuggers are great for digging into this stuff.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Obviously it isn't going inside the `if`, that's because `cssVal` is not a `string`, it's a `CSSStyleRule` object. You should do this instead:

```
cssVal = sheet.cssRules[i];
```

Then in your `if`:

```
if (cssVal.selectorText == '#box')
```

And then, to change the color:

```
cssVal.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This has taught me a lot. I think I had misunderstood the meaning of 'loosely typed'.